# Stability at loop gain <1 and 180 degree phase shift

Tags: operational-amplifier, control, stability, loop-gain

I'm reading this article about stability of OpAmps: [Link to article](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/negative-feedback-part-4-introduction-to-stability/).

It says: "**If Aβ is less than unity at the high frequencies where phase shift reaches 180°, the high-frequency phase-shifted signals will gradually fade away instead of progressively building up into major oscillations.**" This is depicted in the picture below.

However, I don't understand this. Shouldn't the system also be unstable at a loop gain less than 1? The 180 degree phase shift in the loop plus the subtraction at the summing point results in positive feedback (See figure 2 below). 
This means that when a signal is fed into the system (at the control input) it will be attenuated by the loop gain and the phase will be shifted 180 degrees before it arrives back at the summing point. The control signal is still present at the plus input of the summing point so the two signals will be added up resulting in a greater signal than before. When the system keeps doing this the amplitude of the signal will rise to infinity and thus the system will also behave unstable.

**My question: Is there an error in my analysis? Why is it that the system is stable at a loop gain < 1 and a phase shift of 180 degrees?**

[image: According to the article, if the loop gain (A*B) is smaller than 1 at 180 degree phase shift the system is stable]
Figure 1

[image]
Figure 2

Comment: I think your error is thinking that \$1 + A\beta + (A\beta)^2 + (A\beta)^3 + \ldots\$ is infinity. If \$A\beta < 1\$, it is finite and equals \$1 \over 1 - A\beta\$.

Comment: Why is it finite? Let's say the input signal has amplitude 1 and Aβ = -0.5 (- for the 180 degree phase shift). Then after the first round of amplification we have 1 + 1*0.5 = 1.5. In the second round we have 1 + 1.5*0.5 = 1.75. In the third round we have 1 + 1.75*0.5. Etc.. Wouldn't that grow until infinity?

Comment: No: before the first round, the amplification is \$1 = 2 - 1 = 2 - 0.5^0\$; after the first round it is \$1.5 = 2-0.5 = 2-0.5^1\$; after the second round, it is \$1.75 = 2-0.25 = 2-0.5^2\$; …; after the \$n\$th round, it is \$2-0.5^n\$. Hence, it keeps finite.

Comment: For more about the math behind this, you may read about [geometric series at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: Why is the amplification 2-0.5^n?

Comment: @MauricioPaulusma In your own example you can see that the increase gets smaller every time. 1.5 (+0.5), 1.75 (+0.25), 1.875 (+0.125), etc...  So the gain dies out...

Comment: @Unimportant and user2233709, Aah yeah I see I now, it will approach 2 (hence finite). But the still the signal will not die out as long as the input signal is still present, but I guess that is still stable behaviour. Thanks!

Comment: You can perhaps have a look at this seminar which sheds a different light on the subject: http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202009.pdf

Comment: The rate of change of growth or decay is inversely proportional to the gain margin / f-3dB  or excess gain.for oscillator startup unless there are initial conditions

Answer (score 1):

Do a thought experiment. Let the input signal be zero, and see what happens to a single cycle of sine wave, injected at the error channel. Do this for an open loop phase shift of \$\small -180^o\$, and for the three cases:
a.  \$\small 0<A\beta <1\$;
b. \$\small A\beta=1\$; and
c. \$\small A\beta>1\$.
For example, take:
 \$\small A\beta=0.5\$;  \$\small A\beta=1\$; and \$\small A\beta=2\$.
Assume the single cycle travels around the loop discretely, as a packet.

Answer (score -1):

When the gain is >1 with 180 phase shift and another 180 by negative feedback , you have a positive feedback with growing amplitude since  loop gain >1 and non inverting and thus an oscillator. ( i.e. unstable or "astable" )

Where the loop gain >1 at 180 phase shift is the resonant frequency of the oscillator.

The output will be saturated which reduces the gain to 0 when saturated but by this time the stored energy ( sine voltage  feedback) from the reactance that created the 180 phase shift , has enough amplitude.  The DC still is negative feedback so it biases the into near 50% threshold for a square wave out.